# Positive integer expected for recurring interval even when user is not making a recurring contribution

Tags: recurring-contributions

If you enabled the recurring option "Support recurring intervals" on a contribution page you can no longer submit the contribution form unless you enter a value for the recurring interval, even if you have not selected to make a recurring contribution.

Error: recurFrequencyInterval must be a positive integer

This appears to have been introduced with release 5.21.x. This is most likely a result of the work that was released in 5.21.0 with respect to the new class `Civi\Payment\PropertyBag`.

Snippet:

```
$Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(49) "recurFrequencyInterval must be a positive integer"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  object(InvalidArgumentException)#16898 (7) {
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(49) "recurFrequencyInterval must be a positive integer"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(107) ".../civicrm/Civi/Payment/PropertyBag.php"
```

For now I have disabled recurring intervals on the particular contribution page.

Running 5.21.1 on WordPress 5.3.2.

This is reproducible on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ (CiviCRM 5.23.alpha1)

Steps to reproduce:

1. duplicate the existing donation form
2. disable the pledge section
3. enable recurring contributions section, select "Support recurring intervals" + "Offer installments"
4. test the form, leaving the recurring options blank (attempt to make a single donation)

Returns "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
recurFrequencyInterval must be a positive integer"

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org which is development version 5.23alpha1. Are you able to reproduce it there?

Comment: Thanks - I will take a look on dmaster when I have a chance and confirm.

Comment: Thanks @Demerit I finally got around to taking a look at this. Yes, unfortunately this is reproducible on dmaster.demo.

Comment: Ok thanks for the extra steps. Yeah I'd go ahead and post this as a bug on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues and in particular mention that it started in 5.21.

Comment: Thanks @Demerit, finally got around to this, error has been reported here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1588